# Struts2 token interceptor always fails

Tags: struts2, token, interceptor

Im trying to make it so that once i submit this form i cannot hit the back button, but with the current configuration I cannot even get the page/form to load.  I can't seem to figure out why "invalid.token" is always being triggered thus redirecting me to index.jsp no matter what  I have the token tag in my form like im supposed to.  If i use the "excludeMethods" filter and exclude View then my page loads but I can hit the back button freely so it still does not work properly.  I have tried moving the interceptor-ref above and below my noLoginStack but it dosen't make a difference.  Based on my debugging my actual java class isn't even being hit, so its failing before then.  What am I doing wrong?

My action declaration:

```
<action name="viewAppointmentLetter" class="edu.ucr.c3.rsummer.controller.instructor.ManageAppointmentLetters">
        <interceptor-ref name="noLoginStack"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="token" />

        <result name="invalid.token">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error" type="redirectAction">index.do</result>
        <result name="input">/instructor/assigned_appts.jsp</result>
        <result name="view">/instructor/assigned_appts.jsp</result>
        <result type="redirectAction">index.do</result>
    </action>
```

My assigned_appts.jsp:

```
<s:form action="saveAppointmentLetter" onsubmit="return verifySubmit();">
      <s:token name="token" />

      .....
</s:form>
```

If its any clue I always get this in my console

```
WARN  org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper  - Could not find token name in params.
```

Answer (score 1):

In struts2 the order of interceptor is **very** important. you should follow this order.

```
<interceptor-ref name="token"/> 
<interceptor-ref name="noLoginStack"/>
```

Comment: Its always better to provide some description to your answer as it will help others to understand what you trying to convey

Comment: Unfortunately i have tried that as well and I still get the same issue, any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post the complete log?

Answer (score 0):

USe TokenSession interceptor.Had to handle result by `result name="invalid.token"` in struts.xml in specific action.
The page from which your action is generated at that page you have to write `<s:token>` tag in the header